# wont add updated check boxes from gridview to arraylist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

On my aspx page I have a gridview template that when it is rendered has 100 - 200 rows and each row has a check box.

When the page loads 5 check boxes are automatically checked. If I manually check another 3 then press the submit button, then loop through all the gridview rows to find out which rows had a checked box  then it still remembers the original 5. How do I make it remember the updated  8?

```
Protected Sub mySubmitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Dim myArray As ArrayList = New ArrayList()

            For Each myRow As GridViewRow In MyGridview.Rows

                If CType(myRow.FindControl("MyCheckbox"), CheckBox).Checked Then

                    myArray.Add(MyGridview.DataKeys(MyRow.RowIndex).Value)

                End If

            Next

           'add to DB myArray


End Sub
```

I tried this on the gridview in the asp.net and it made no difference

```
ViewStateMode="Disabled" and ViewStateMode="Enabled"
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the ViewState enabled on the GridView?

Have you got the logic to load your Grid in the Page_Load event, if so add it in if(!IsPostBack)

Comment: [Click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) to understand ViewState.